# Google Maps Javascript API on Firefox OS 2.0

Tags: google-maps-api-3, firefox-os

I am building a Firefox OS app that uses Google Maps Javascript API. It seems that Firefox OS doesnt support it yet.

If I open [this demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) in Firefox OS browser on Flame device running FFOS 2.0, it doesnt work. It just shows a big grey box instead of the map.

Any tips on getting this working?

**EDIT:** It works in FFOS 1.3 but not in 2.0

Comment: I can view the demo on Flame 1.3. Did you check 1.3 before updating to 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it is working in 1.3. How do I get it working in 2.0?

Comment: The demo works for me (2.2 build id 20141117013047)

Comment: Please file a bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)